# Works only on index page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

With this communities help, I placed this code on my master frames page. On the front page all links are accessible, everything works.
On the rest of the site, links all display as they should if a user is logged on or not, but the links are dead. You can hover over them and they respond, but when you click, nothing happens. Not sure why this is happening.

```
<span id="LoginName1"><?php
if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
{

?>
<div id="wb_Text2" style="">
<span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:13px;"><a href="javascript:displaylightbox('./members/Edit_Profile.php',{width:620,height:710})" target="_self" class="style5">Profile</a></span>
</div>

<?php
}
else
{
    ?>
<div id="wb_Text4" style="">
<span style="color:#FFA500;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:13px;line-height:19px;"><a href="javascript:displaylightbox('./members/Create_Account.php',{width:620,height:710})" target="_self" title="Create New Account" class="style5">REGISTER</a><br><a href="javascript:displaylightbox('./members/Forgot_Password.php',{width:350,height:275})" target="_self" title="Forgot Password" class="style5">Forgot Password?</a><br></span><span style="color:#000000;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:27px;line-height:31px;"><strong><a href="javascript:displaylightbox('./members/Log-In.php',{width:490,height:370})" target="_self" class="style5">Log-In</a></strong></span>
</div>
<?php
}
?></span>
```

Comment: You are using relative URIs. So the final URL calculated by the browser will depend on the calling URI. Have a look at the developer console of your browser or at the logs of your webserver to get an idea what a browser does when finding relative URIs.

Comment: there might be a problem with your relative path please make sure your paths are correct when you are not on index page

Comment: check your console for errors is `displaylightbox()` defined? Means you included js file or not function is defined in;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the browser console by pressing F12 key. You will get some errors when you click on link.

This errors should be related to displaylightbox() function.

**So the solution should be :**
Compare included JS files on homepage with other pages. And put mission Js on other pages.

Hope you understood well. Thanx!!

Comment: Since I have this code all in a masterframe, is it already not on all pages? When I click f11 it just makes the screen full size, when I click the link it still does nothing and no errors are being made.

Comment: Sorry. Have to press F12.

Comment: So yes it is showing an error: VM157:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: displaylightbox is not defined, So if I add super() will that work and if so where in the code will it go?

Comment: check all js files and search **displaylightbox** keyword. Then include that perticular js to all pages. you can check homepage's js files.